# Code doesn't execute, while storing data's to ms-access database from c#?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I have 2 set of data's like Master and Details. I Stored both details separately in two tables eg **Table1** & **Table2**. I have query to insert data's into **Table1** and then want to get `UniqueId` from **Table1** and then using that `UniqueId` **Table2** is get stored.

Example

```
INSERT INTO Table1(TempId, Name, Address, Language) VALUES (1, "XYZ", "ABCD", "English");

//Now Table is like this
UniqueId   TempId   Name   Address        Language
1          1        Ram    3rd Street     Hindi
2          2        Paul   1st Street     Hindi
3          1        XYZ    ABCD           English
```

Here **UniqueId** is Primary Key Auto Increment. After storing **Table1**, I get `UniqueId` using TempId & Language. Then insert data's into **Table2**.

```
int id=UniqueId; // This value comes from MS Access Database
INSERT INTO Table2(UniqueId, Detail1, Details2, Detail3) VALUES (id, "Det1", "Det2", "Det3");
```

This is my task. Now problem is I have code to get **UniqueId** that part didn't work, Stores **Table1** and then directly stores **Tables2**. When I open **Table2** in Access Database **UniqueId** set to **zero**.

If I use break point to check the errors, now line by line execute and it retrieve **UniqueId** from **Table1** after it stores and then all data's stored in **Table2** successfully. What is problem here ? While storing we cont able to get data? If I use break point it will works fine why? Help me if possible.

---

`UniqueId` is Auto Increment Primary key in **Table1** It generate if we store a new row into **Table1**.

```
INSERT INTO Table1()VALUES()....
```

thn i have code to get **UniqueId** `SELECT UniqueId FROM Table1 WHERE MyCondition.....`

```
INSERT INTO Table2(Id,...)VALUES(id,...)....
```

Comment: can you please provide what is the error?

Comment: It wont show any errors, Simply store 0 in Access database UniqeId

Comment: how do you get UniqueId when inserting to Table2? can you provide the code parts?

Comment: I updated my question. Check is it clear or ?

Comment: what is _yourcondition_? can you get the UniqueId successfully with that? as I understand you can get the UniqueId when debugging, but other times it stores 0 as UniqueId. am I right? this is not a hard problem, but I'm just making random guesses here. if you can provide some ACTUAL code, I can point you to some direction.

Comment: Yeah perfect.  Get the UniqueId when debugging, but other times it stores 0 as UniqueId.

Comment: you do the insert operation, then select the UniqueId. insert operation hasn't been finished yet, so you get 0 as default. you need to submit your change to the database; make sure the insertion is complete, only then select the UniqueId. while debugging, process is slow and insertion is submitted, but while running normally, you try to select while/before the insertion. please provide the C# code to point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have only a little experience in MS Access, but you can try this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(Detail1, Details2, Detail3) VALUES ("Det1", "Det2", "Det3");
```

As `ID` is automatically assigned. This is the case in most of the databases I've used.

Comment: No my requirement is want to get `id` from **Table1** and use that `id` and store into **Table2**.

Comment: This all process must done in a button click.

Comment: if you will do the insertion only by that machine, it won't matter. just do the insertion to table2 after table1, as they will be holding the same Id and giving the same seed.